# Best performing way to emulate integer overflow?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, integer-overflow

I'm mucking about with hash functions, porting some classics like murmur or fnv families and creating my own, for fun, really. I know js isn't exactly an ideal environment for this but whatever.

The biggest obstacle I run into is the fact that js uses doubles for most arithmetics. Almost every single hash function I've ever seen exploits integer overflow by multiplication. For example, I take the input of 7 and multiply it by some big prime like 0x5bd1e995, this multiplication amplifies the significance of that little input into every single bit of the result which is really neat for hash functions.

Unfortunately this falls totally flat when using doubles to do the math because doubles won't overflow like integers (preserving least significant bits) but instead attempt to preserve the magnitude of the result (preserving most significant bits) and that screws with the design of almost any hash function.

The few ways I've found to deal with this are to

1. Modulo the input before multiplying to make sure the result doesn't exceed Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
2. Do the multiplication after splitting the input into two 16 bit values and recombine
3. Use a variety of magic numbers depending on the input to make sure I stay in doubles range of integers

Problem is though, none of these are fast and cut the performance into shreds. So, question time: Is there a well performing way to emulate integer overflow behavior in js in case of a multiplication that will almost definitely exceed Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER?

Comment: Do you mean like a c type int multiplication? It simply truncates the top bits and leaves the lower 32 during overflow. If you want that look at `Math.imul`.

Comment: I guess [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) is #4 in your list of possibly but slow options?

Comment: @HanYolo Exactly that yes, looking into it!

Comment: @AhmedFasih Yes, BigInt is technically an option but slower than everything else combined.

Comment: If you're going to use `imul`, you probably want to do so in asm.js block. You don't need to put everything in it, only the hottest calculations.

Comment: Maybe JavaScript is just not the right language.

Comment: I wonder if you could simulate any of this with typed arrays. I haven't looked into doing math ops or anything crazy with them before, but it might be worth investigating.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Comment: @zero298 the problem is that as soon as you fetch a value from a typed numeric array, it turns into an ordinary JavaScript number.

Comment: @pointy well thats disappointing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look into [Math.imul](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/imul).

This multiplies numbers as 32bit ints and simply truncates the overflow bits.